# Junit - Executing a class with variety of tests that resides on different classes

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have the following test classes:

```
TestClass1 (10 tests)
TestClass2 (20 tests)
TestClass3 (15 tests)
TestClass4 (25 tests)
```

I would like to create a test class called

```
 SmallTestClass
```

that executes 2 tests from TestClass1, 3 tests from TestClass2, 5 tests from TestClass3, 4 tests from TestClass4

How can a achieve this ?  I Use spring framework and junit 4

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I Want to create a sanity test that runs a very small subset of all my test classes. this sanity test is general and quick. If i run all the classes than i will have to wait 5 hours for the tests to complete.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a combination of Junit 4 `Category` and `Suite` to achieve this. Note that the `Category` is still an experimental feature, having been introduced in `v4.8`.

The below example would only ensure only `someTest1()` gets run (I used `v4.11` myself to test) since it's categorized to be a `SanityTest`.

The aggregator:

```
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Categories;
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Categories.IncludeCategory;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith (Categories.class)
@SuiteClasses (SomeTest.class)
@IncludeCategory (SanityTests.class)
public class JunitSuiteTest {
}
```

The class containing the actual tests:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Category;

public class SomeTest {
    @Test
    @Category (SanityTests.class)
    public void someTest1()
    {
        System.out.println("test 1");
    }

    @Test
    public void someTest2()
    {
        System.out.println("test 2");
    }
}
```

A marker class to help categorize:

```
public class SanityTests {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But i'm afraid that this experimental feature will change in the future. Here is an upvote for the effort